# PyQt5 -- Unable to playback video from stream

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

I've seen a number of other questions like this floating around but it seems many of them are unresolved or unrelated to my situation, so here goes.

I'm attempting to play back a video stored as serialized data (through pickle) on a mongodb collection.

Here's the code:

```
    binary_file = my_database_entry['binary video']
    unpickle = pickle.dumps(binary_file)

    outByteArray = QByteArray(unpickle)
    mediaStream = QBuffer()
    mediaStream.setBuffer(outByteArray)
    mediaStream.open(QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(), mediaStream)
    mediaPlayer.play()
```

where 'my_database_entry' is the mongoDB entry and 'binary video' is the dictionary key for the pickled video entry.
This also assumes that mediaPlayer is properly created and initialized within my user interface i.e.

```
    mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
    videoPlayer = QVideoWidget()
    mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(videoPlayer)
```

I also tried initializing mediaPlayer with a 'QMediaPlayer.StreamPlayback' flag but again, nothing.

It crashes when I try it on windows and it's just a black screen when I try it on mac. No error logs or anything (nothing enlightening at any rate).

Has anyone gotten this to successfully work for them and if so, how did you do it?

Thanks!
-Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to both the buffer and the underlying data, otherwise they will just be garbage-collected after the player starts.

And note that in your example, it is utterly pointless pickling the video data, as it is just bytes and so there's nothing worth serializing. Pickle is only useful for structured python objects, such as a `list` or `dict`.

Below is a demo script with a complete video player. It initally gets the video resource from the file-system, but it would work just the same if it came from a database:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(self)
        self.viewer = QtMultimediaWidgets.QVideoWidget(self)
        self.player.setVideoOutput(self.viewer)
        self.player.stateChanged.connect(self.handleStateChanged)
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Play', self)
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Stop', self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.player.stop)
        self.button2.setEnabled(False)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.viewer, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.button1, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.button2, 1, 1)
        self._buffer = QtCore.QBuffer(self)
        self._data = None

    def handleButton(self):
        path = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self)[0]
        if path:
            self.button1.setEnabled(False)
            self.button2.setEnabled(True)
            with open(path, 'rb') as stream:
                self._data = stream.read()
                self._buffer.setData(self._data)
                self._buffer.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)
                self.player.setMedia(
                    QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(), self._buffer)
                self.player.play()

    def handleStateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.StoppedState:
            self._buffer.close()
            self._data = None
            self.button1.setEnabled(True)
            self.button2.setEnabled(False)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.setGeometry(500, 50, 640, 480)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

**UPDATE**:

The solution above will only work on Windows and Linux, because there is currently no support for streaming on OSX:

- See: [Qt Multimedia Backends](http://wiki.qt.io/Qt_Multimedia_Backends)

Comment: That was exactly it. Works perfectly. In my case I didn't explain it well enough for brevity's sake. I still needed to unpickle the data in order for it to work. Unpickling basically took the place of the 'with open(path, 'rb') as stream:' etc line of your code. Thanks again!!

Comment: So I encountered a bit of an issue with this method. It works fine on a windows machine but going to OSX I just get a black screen. No noticeable error. Is this some sort of mac-specific bug perhaps?

Comment: @huitlacoche. I only tried it Linux, and I cannot test it myself on OSX. It may be the media itself that is causing the problem, so I suggest you try a few different video formats. Have you tried loading the same media directly using a file url? I don't know how reliable Qt Multimedia is in general, as I've never really used it in a serious project. (PS: I just tried a few more files on Linux, and one or two didn't load successfully - not sure why).

Comment: @huitlacoche. PPS: I tried loading the problematic files directly using a file url, and they still didn't load - so it's not reading from a buffer that is causing the problem. And the same files load okay using mplayer, so there seems to be some internal Qt issue.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's the source. I can load the videos just fine from the file url. I'll keep playing with it. At least I know it *can* work. Thanks!

Comment: ...and I take that back. It won't work because according to the Qt backend compatibility docs, streaming is *not* supported on ios/osx. Dang it.

Comment: @huitlacoche. I knew I'd seen something about backend compatibility before, but I just couldn't find it yesterday. I've now added the relevant link to my answer. However, that page states both local and remote urls are supported, so maybe you could run a [simple http server](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#module-http.server) to supply your video content (no need to use local files, just reimplement the `GET` handler and send the data straight from your database).

Comment: Given the small size of the videos that I am using, re-creating them from the binary data is pretty simple and fast. I'd have to run some tests with a separate server to know if it's an improvement. I guess my thought there is that I hit the database already to get the relevant video information (and the server location to the video) and then hit another server to grab said video. It'd probably be a wash or possibly a bit slower. But then I won't know unless I try. Right now it works okay in test phases. Nothing to be said about it being used by dozens of other people at the same time. heh.