# QML: Stream USB Camera feed from PyQT5

Tags: python, camera, pyqt5, qml

I am still very new to QML and PyQT. With that said, I am working on creating a relatively simple UI. This UI has some controls and a I am hoping to add a USB camera feed. However, I am not sure how to get frames from the camera and have those be displayed in the QML UI. Right now I have a basic VideoOutput item that I was hoping to use for the camera feed.

```
  VideoOutput {
        x: 10
        y: 10
        width: 1410
        height: 576
        source: camera
        objectName: "Camera"
    }
```

I was hoping someone could provide some sample code of how to do this with QML/PyQT? It has been very difficult to find any good sources for PyQT5 and QML examples so I hope I am not asking too much.

I was looking at this but I think its a bit different than what I need to do: [PyQt5 -- Unable to playback video from stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150162/pyqt5-unable-to-playback-video-from-stream)

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Did you try [the example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#details) from Qt docs? Or [this](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtmultimedia-multimedia-declarative-camera-example.html) one? Just 2 first rows from Google search by `QML`, `Camera`.

Comment: None of those use PyQT5. The frames would be coming from PyQT to the QML view. I understand how to do it in QML as my starting code is based on the first example you provided. What I would like to know is how to pass the frames from the Python code to the QML view.